# Como selecionar últimos registros de tabela relacionada?

Tags: mysql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas: `negociacoes`, `negociacao_contatos` e `negociacao_status` e os seguintes relacionamentos:

```
negociacoes hasMany negociacao_contatos

negociacoes belongsTo negociacao_status
```

Em `negociacao_status` tenho dois campos: `alerta_usuario` (Y/N) e `prazo_alerta` (int).

Preciso fazer uma busca (COUNT) de `negociacoes` em que seu status `(negociacao.negociacao_status_id)` seja `alerta_usuario = "Y"` e `negociacao_contatos.created` seja maior que `prazo_alerta`.

Ou seja, preciso contar quantas negociações existem em que o último contato foi realizado há mais de X dias. Como seria a maneira mais correta de fazer esta busca? Já tentei diversas alternativas, nenhuma com sucesso.

Comment: poderia colocar um exemplo das tabelas e atributos na pergunta? Fica mais facil de entender e montar a resposta

Comment: @SneepSNinjA está ali na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma como (finalmente) consegui resolver o problema foi a seguinte:

```
SELECT 
Negociacao.id,Cliente.nome,NegociacaoStatus.nome,NegociacaoContato.created,DATEDIFF(NOW(),NegociacaoContato.created) AS dias
FROM negociacoes AS Negociacao
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT NC.negociacao_id,NC.created,max(NC.id) AS id 
        FROM negociacao_contatos AS NC 
        GROUP BY negociacao_id
    ) AS NegociacaoContato2
ON NegociacaoContato2.negociacao_id = Negociacao.id
LEFT JOIN negociacao_status AS NegociacaoStatus 
ON Negociacao.negociacao_status_id = NegociacaoStatus.id
LEFT JOIN clientes AS Cliente
ON Negociacao.cliente_id = Cliente.id
LEFT JOIN negociacao_contatos AS NegociacaoContato
ON NegociacaoContato.id = NegociacaoContato2.id
WHERE NegociacaoStatus.finaliza != "Y"
AND Negociacao.consultor_id = 23
AND Negociacao.ativo = "Y"
AND NegociacaoStatus.alerta_usuario = "Y"
AND datediff(now(),NegociacaoContato.created) >= NegociacaoStatus.prazo_alerta
ORDER BY dias DESC
```

Agradeço a todos pelas contribuições. Através delas que consegui chegar neste resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Se bem entendi será qualquer coisa assim:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

A query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM negociacao_status as ns 
INNER JOIN negociacoes         as n  on n.negociacoes_status_id = ns.id 
INNER JOIN negociacao_contatos as nc on nc.negociacoes_id       = n.id  
WHERE ns.alerta_usuario = "Y" AND nc.created > ns.prazo_alerta ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo as mesmas configurações de tabelas do Jorge B. porém sem o uso do *JOIN* ficaria assim:

```
    select count(*) 
    from negociacoes n, negociacao_contatos nc, negociacao_status ns       
    where ns.id = n.negociacoes_status_id 
      and n.id = nc.negociacoes_id 
      and ns.alerta_usuario='Y' 
      and nc.created > ns.prazo_alerta;
```

Considerando que as tabelas estejam assim:

```
CREATE TABLE `negociacao_contatos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `negociacoes_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `negociacao_status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alerta_usuario` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prazo_alerta` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `negociacoes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `negociacoes_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```